# Scanning all columns from Hbase in Pentaho

Tags: hbase, pentaho, pdi

I am new to Pentaho and HBase. I want to read all the columns from Hbase table and load it in a flat file using Pentaho.

One main thing is that, columns in my Hbase table is not static. Some days I will be getting 30+ columns and some days it may change to 50+.

I tried using 'Hbase Input' in PDI. But I cant able to define number of columns. Is there any way to define the dynamic changing columns in Pentaho??

Answer (score 0):

Don't mention any column names. If no column names are mentioned, It takes all mandatory columns in to consideration.

Step 1: In HBase Input step, under "create/ edit mapping" tab, call the required Hbase table name and create a new mapping name for that table.
Step 2: Then Click on 'Create a tuple template'. 5 columns will be getting generated.
Step 3: click 'Save mapping' and move the previous tab 'configure query'.
Step 4: Click 'Get mapped table name' and select the same table for which you have called under "Create/edit mapping" tab. Like the same call the mapping nams by clicking 'Get mappings for the specified table'.
Step 5: Click on 'Get Key/Fields info'. You will get 5 columns.
step 6: Now keep only three required columns (Key, column,value).

Now your Pentaho job is ready to get the columns for your required manipulation.